# Flask HTML Escape Decorator

Tags: python, flask

How would I use a decorator on a route to HTML escape its output. That is, how do I write the `html_escape` function here:

```
@app.route('/')
@html_escape
def index():
    return '<html></html>'
```

(I feel like there should be an extension for this and other simple decorators)

Comment: Why don't just use the [templates](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/templates/)?

Comment: @KevinGuan because its an API server

Comment: @Cyrin: so? That doesn't mean templates cannot be used to produce escaped text.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but it does mean I dont want to use templates to produce escaped text

Comment: You don't need to, but you *are* producing text. That is what templates do, produce text, and as a tool should not just be dismissed out of hand.

Comment: Also, *why you don't want to use templates to produce escaped text?* Anything that templates can't do?

Comment: The #1 goal is simplicity and clarity. For those reasons, I dont like to use templates in API servers, they contradict my mental model of how a (small) API server should be operate.

(EDIT) A lot of my thoughts on Flask API servers come from Miguel Grinberg's talk here https://speakerdeck.com/miguelgrinberg/creating-a-rest-api-with-python-and-flask-pydx-2015

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Flask has its own `escape`, doc: [flask.escape](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.escape)

so, you can:

```
from flask import escape

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return escape("<html></html>")
```

if you insist on using decorator:

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import escape

def my_escape(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return escape(func(*args, **kwargs))
    return wrapped

@app.route('/')
@my_escape
def index():
    return "<html></html>"
```

Comment: Any difference in functionality between flask.escape() and cgi.escape()?

Comment: flask.escape escape: `& < > ‘ ”`  
cgi.escape escapes:  `& < >` and if a flag is set `"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
html_escape_table = {
    "&": "&amp;",
    '"': "&quot;",
    "'": "&apos;",
    ">": "&gt;",
    "<": "&lt;",
}
def html_escape(text):
    return "".join(html_escape_table.get(c,c) for c in text)

print html_escape("<a>test</a>")

result -> &lt;a&gt;test&lt;/a&gt;
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is what I found from searching for "flask escape" so might as well add here:
According to Flask's `__init__.py`, `flask.escape` has been deprecated and `markupsafe.escape` should be used instead

Comment: Looking at flask's current docs this is still very much a valid method https://tedboy.github.io/flask/interface_api.useful_funcs.html#flask.escape

Comment: Maybe they didn't update the docs. It did not work for `3.0.0` but did for `2.3.0`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `cgi` module's `escape` function to do the escaping. Assuming that your function only returns a string, it can be as simple as  the following:

```
import cgi


def html_escape(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return cgi.escape(func(*args, **kwargs))
    return wrapped


@html_escape
def index():
    return "<html></html>"

print index()
```