# Securing a POST request on Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I built a simple Flask application that receives a POST request and performs some actions after receiving it. Here is my simple code:

```
@app.route('/<user>/', methods=['POST'])
def Receiver(user):
    Query = User.query.filter_by(token=user)
    Content = request.data.decode('UTF-8')
    Data = {'Content': Content, 'Username': Query.Username, 'UserID': Query.UserID}
    return jsonify(Data)
```

I would like to make this code as safe as possible, but i'm just getting started to Flask and security in general. What dangers can i run using this code? I'm using the variable `user` to make a query to my database, can it be harmful if that variable gets set to an SQL query, for example? What other threats should i consider in this case?

Comment: I would recommend looking at SQL Injections and how to protect your database from them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here some of my thoughts to your question:

1. Why is this a POST request and not a GET request? [POST requests are meant to change data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)), GETs are for queries.
2. You don't validate input data. What happens, if the user sends you e.g. a 100kB long user name? How will the database handle it? Will it have impact on performance? Will it allow a DOS attack on server/database?
3. Yes, SQL injection too. Everywhere where relational databases are concerned.
4. What if the user ID does not exist? Should we not return 404?
5. What is actually security? What is safety? The two terms are not interchangeable. Safety is when the code does not harm the world. Security is when the world does not harm the code.
6. There is a wide variety of things to consider that could impact your code security (meaning providing confidentiality, integrity and accessibility of the data the code touches), that are unrelated to your code like: communication channel protection, server misconfigurations, DDOS attacks... Even if your code is perfect, the system holding it might still be insecure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the POST request doesn't depend on me, since i'm dealing with a third party. I'm returning a 404 if the user doesn't exist. You're right on all the points, i'll work on my code according to what you suggested

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to what Marek said, would also recommend changing to a GET... As long as there's no sensitive information being passed along in the URL. [This](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) link nicely explains the differences. It might be a good idea to look at encrypting the URL token string too, so that any parameters aren't passed over in plain text, as this leaves room for vulnerability.

Alongside this, if the site is to be made live- definitely ensure to use SSL encryption.

In terms of SQL validation, you'll need to sanitize the input before it ever reaches the database. You can do this in Flask, simply by using the HTML escape special chars... But Flask provides their own function. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33490888/flask-html-escape-decorator) link might help in that regard.

In terms of error handling, I found [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-vii-error-handling) tutorial mighty useful. That whole series of blog posts walks you right the way through.

Comment: Thank you a lot! As i said on the other answer, the request is  made by a third party, so unfortunately i can't make it a GET request. Thank you for the links!

Comment: No problem, If it's GET then definitely look into the URI token encryption. Another thing worth looking into might be token based authentication. Yet another link :) https://realpython.com/token-based-authentication-with-flask/  Another security concern would be the database itself. If possible, put the database on a completely separate server, and have it talking to the Flask server on a private NIC- i.e. on a 10.0 range or something. Alongside this, ensure that server is secure :) https://www.upguard.com/blog/11-steps-to-secure-sql

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you a lot! Token auth is something i was considering, but the problem is that i can't force the third party to change their request to include a token auth, although it would be the best thing to do. I was already considering of putting the db on a different server, that's what i'll do :)

Comment: Also, one final thing, I assume you're using SQLAlchemy, but this advice applies even if you're connecting to the raw database. Rather than having a db URI inside the same flask app like this: `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST/DATABASE'`  - I'd create a separate file called something like config.py, store the DB URI in a class, then import that class into the flask app. Doing it this way just basically modularizes the file structure.